# How to disable keycloak login page prompt when there is no authentication but just immediately return 401?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot application with Keycloak, and I have no issues with it in the normal case (access_token is provided)

However, if the requests do not have any authentication in the header, Keycloak returns a login page with a response of 400 Bad Request.

I expected it to return 401 Unauthorized if there is no Authentication header in the request.
How to configure Keycloak to do this?

My application.properties file in my spring application, in case it helps:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://192.168.1.251:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=applicationName
keycloak.resource=applicationName-client
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=admin-user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[1]=standard-user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].methods[0]=GET
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/devices
keycloak.security-constraints[1].authRoles[0]=admin-user
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].methods[0]=POST
keycloak.security-constraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/devices
keycloak.security-constraints[2].authRoles[0]=admin-user
keycloak.security-constraints[2].authRoles[1]=standard-user
keycloak.security-constraints[2].securityCollections[0].methods[0]=GET
keycloak.security-constraints[2].securityCollections[0].methods[1]=PATCH
keycloak.security-constraints[2].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/device/*
keycloak.security-constraints[3].authRoles[0]=admin-user
keycloak.security-constraints[3].securityCollections[0].methods[0]=PUT
keycloak.security-constraints[3].securityCollections[0].methods[1]=DELETE
keycloak.security-constraints[3].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/device/*
```

In case this may also help, I get the access token using the following url:

```
http://192.168.1.251:8080/auth/realms/applicationName/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

With the following parameters:

```
client_id : applicationName-client
username: user
password: password1234
grant_type: password
client_secret: <secret>
scope: openid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the trick is in registering a custom authentication entry point and overriding the one Keycloak brings with it.

After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776431/how-to-disable-keycloak-login-page-prompt-when-there-is-no-authentication-but-ju) I fixed my issue by adding the following to my security
config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    //THE SOLUTION IS BELOW
    .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {

                @Override
                public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());

                }
        
    });
}
```